# Failing to fill 0x quote

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to fill a quote -from within my contract- that I get from the 0x API v1:

URL: https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=TUSD&buyToken=WETH&sellAmount=882693000000000051118080&slippagePercentage=0.8

...but it reverts, even after successfully getting the quote (taker has the sell balance, allowance was granted, value of the fee is 0).

When the quote has one `order`, the swaps runs, but when it has two or more `orders` (like in my quote), it reverts:

One `order`:

[image]

Two `orders` (reverts):

[image]

My `fillquote` function:

```js
function fillQuote(
        address sellToken,
        address buyToken,
        address spender,
        address swapTarget,
        bytes calldata swapCallData
    ) public   
    {        
        require(MyIERC20(sellToken).approve(spender, type(uint).max));
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = swapTarget.call(swapCallData);
        if (!success) {
            console.log(Helpers._getRevertMsg(returnData));
        }
        require(success, 'SWAP_CALL_FAILED');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

My contract is a hardhat fork with a pinned block to an old state from mainnet, and the 0x API makes offchain requests to the current state, so the liquidity that appears on the quote is not the same as that the contract aims to fill.

This ***could be and most likely is*** the reason why it's failing since when I doubled the gas on the call, and check -with `gasleft()`- the amount of `gas` taken on the execution, it was roughly 90k -after failure- when I had passed over 1M in `gas` to the call.